# Python Json TypeError: string indices must be integers error

Tags: python

I am studying Python while looking at the textbook. 
However, there was an error in the code I wrote after reading the book, and I found out what the problem was by searching the error source, but I don't know how to correct it.
TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

consumer_key = 'check consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'check consumer_secret'
access_token = 'check access_token'
access_token_secret = 'check access_token_secret'

oauth = OAuth1(client_key=consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret,
resource_owner_key=access_token, resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret)

url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={0}'.format('naver_d2')
r = requests.get(url=url,auth=oauth)

statuses = r.json()

for status in statuses:
   print(status['text'], status['created_at'])
```

Comment: You can use `status['text']` only if `status` is dictionary. You could check what is the type of status by printing it or printing it's type `print(type(status))` inside your loop

Comment: Please post the json content and the full traceback. This being said, as the error message states, you are trying to subscript a string, so chances are `statuses` is actually a `dict` (in which case you're iterating over the keys, which are strings in the case of something decoded from json) and that what you're looking for are the values for one of the dict's keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a list via a string that's why you are receiving such error.You can only use `status[text]` if status is a dictionary
Moreover, replace your URL with `https` to not receive an SSL error

URL should be `"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name={0}".format('naver_d2')`

Comment: print(type(status['text'])), (type(status['created_at'])) Is it right?

Comment: You can first output your statuses. accordingly we can check whether it will work or not